# How to execute Curl command with additional command inside?

Tags: linux, curl

I want to run the following command:

```
curl -X PUT $URL -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"payload": $(base64 /some/path)`}'
```

I'm having trouble running the command in ESLinux environment (tcsh) because it can't execute `$(base64 /some/path)`. Getting `Illegal variable name` which makes sense because using this syntax is bash and not tcsh. How can I execute it? Tried to use backticks but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks should work. Note you need some more double quote characters to get the json syntax correct

```
curl -X PUT $URL -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"payload": "'`base64 /some/path`'"}'
```

The -d parameter is built up in 3 pieces

```
   '{"payload": "'
   `base64 /some/path`
   '"}'
```

The first and third use single quotes, so everything inside them is preserved, including the double quotes. In particular the final value for the -d parameter will look like `{ "payload": "af5143676d6d6d6a bcdefc8844"}` with the double quotes around the hex string and with embedded spaces replacing the newlines in the output of base64. The far end may not like the spaces.

Comment: `base64 -w0 /some/path`